# Rename [dragon-age-awakening] → [dragon-age-origins-awakening]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

The tag for [*Dragon Age: Origins – Awakening*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Age:_Origins_%E2%80%93_Awakening) should probably be expanded to the full name, thanks to the 35 character tag limit.

- [dragon-age-awakening](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-age-awakening) → [dragon-age-origins-awakening](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-age-origins-awakening)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done:**

- [dragon-age-awakening](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-age-awakening) → [dragon-age-origins-awakening](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-age-origins-awakening)